# Xml file and why my Xslt file do not work

Tags: xml, xslt

Please see below extract form the Gleif Xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <lei:LEIData xmlns:lei="http://www.leiroc.org/data/schema/leidata/2014"       xmlns:gleif="http://www.gleif.org/concatenated-file/header-extension/1.1">
       <lei:LEIRecords>
    <lei:LEIRecord>
      <lei:LEI>01J4SO3XTWZF4PP38209</lei:LEI>
      <lei:Entity>
        <lei:LegalName>Trustmark National Bank</lei:LegalName>
        <lei:LegalAddress>
          <lei:Line1>248 East Capitol Street</lei:Line1>
          <lei:City>Jackson</lei:City>
          <lei:Region>US-MS</lei:Region>
          <lei:Country>US</lei:Country>
          <lei:PostalCode>39201-2503</lei:PostalCode>
        </lei:LegalAddress>
        <lei:HeadquartersAddress>
          <lei:Line1>248 East Capitol Street</lei:Line1>
          <lei:City>Jackson</lei:City>
          <lei:Region>US-MS</lei:Region>
          <lei:Country>US</lei:Country>
          <lei:PostalCode>39201-2503</lei:PostalCode>
        </lei:HeadquartersAddress>
        <lei:BusinessRegisterEntityID register="RA888888">4988</lei:BusinessRegisterEntityID>
        <lei:LegalJurisdiction>US-MS</lei:LegalJurisdiction>
        <lei:LegalForm>OTHER</lei:LegalForm>
        <lei:EntityStatus>ACTIVE</lei:EntityStatus>
      </lei:Entity>
      <lei:Registration>
        <lei:InitialRegistrationDate>2012-06-06T15:51:37.855Z</lei:InitialRegistrationDate>
        <lei:LastUpdateDate>2017-12-02T10:41:33.347Z</lei:LastUpdateDate>
        <lei:RegistrationStatus>ISSUED</lei:RegistrationStatus>
        <lei:NextRenewalDate>2018-12-02T10:41:33.348Z</lei:NextRenewalDate>
        <lei:ManagingLOU>5493001KJTIIGC8Y1R12</lei:ManagingLOU>
        <lei:ValidationSources>FULLY_CORROBORATED</lei:ValidationSources>
      </lei:Registration>
    </lei:LEIRecord>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <lei_LEIData>
      <lei_LEIRecords>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="lei_LEIData/lei_LEIRecords/lei_LEIRecord"/>
      </lei_LEIRecords>
  </lei_LEIData>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="lei_LEIData/lei_LEIRecords/lei_LEIRecord">
    <lei_LEIRecord>
      <xsl:for-each select="
                    lei_LEI|lei_Entity/lei_LegalName|lei_Entity/lei_BusinessRegisterEntityID|
                    lei_Entity/lei_LegalJurisdiction|lei_Entity/lei_LegalForm|
                    lei_LegalForm/lei_EntityStatus|
                    lei_Registration/lei_InitialRegistrationDate|
                    lei_Registration/lei_LastUpdateDate|
                    lei_Registration/lei_RegistrationStatus|
                    lei_Registration/lei_NextRenewalDate|
                    lei_Registration/lei_ManagingLOU|
                    lei_Registration/lei_ValidationSources                   
                    ">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="
                    lei_Entity/lei_BusinessRegisterEntityID/@register
                    ">
        <xsl:attribute name="register">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="
                    lei_Entity/lei_LegalAddress/lei_Line1|
                    lei_Entity/lei_LegalAddress/lei_City|
                    lei_Entity/lei_LegalAddress/lei_Country|
                    lei_Entity/lei_LegalAddress/lei_PostalCode                   
                    ">
          <xsl:attribute name="legaladdress_{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="
                    lei_Entity/lei_HeadquartersAddress/lei_Line1|
                    lei_Entity/lei_HeadquartersAddress/lei_City|
                    lei_Entity/lei_HeadquartersAddress/lei_Country|
                    lei_Entity/lei_HeadquartersAddress/lei_PostalCode                   
                    ">
        <xsl:attribute name="headquarter_{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </lei_LEIRecord>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hi.. :)

I have the above Xml file and the XSLT file below And I do not understand why when I use the xslt file to transform, that it does not produce any output.

Thank you in advance for your answer and help...

Comment: Your whole XML file has a namespace `xmlns:lei="http://www.leiroc.org/data/schema/leidata/2014"`. You have to add that in the XSLT as well and add `lei:` prefixes on your elements/matching rules.

Comment: Like this : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> <lei:LEIData xmlns:lei="http://www.leiroc.org/data/schema/leidata/2014"

Comment: Could you give an example of "lei: prefixes on your elements/matching rules" ?

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It works great ! Thank you for the answer ab your comments   Kind regards Jesper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a string-replace on your XSLT file and replaced all `lei_` with `lei:` to use them as prefixes. Then I added the namespace

```
xmlns:lei="http://www.leiroc.org/data/schema/leidata/2014"
```

on the `xsl:stylesheet` element. Then I replaced the `name()` XPath expressions with `local-name()` expressions. That's all I did to make it work.

Here is the fixed XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:lei="http://www.leiroc.org/data/schema/leidata/2014" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <lei:LEIData>
      <lei:LEIRecords>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="lei:LEIData/lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord"/>
      </lei:LEIRecords>
  </lei:LEIData>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="lei:LEIData/lei:LEIRecords/lei:LEIRecord">
    <lei:LEIRecord>
      <xsl:for-each select="
                    lei:LEI|lei:Entity/lei:LegalName|lei:Entity/lei:BusinessRegisterEntityID|
                    lei:Entity/lei:LegalJurisdiction|lei:Entity/lei:LegalForm|
                    lei:LegalForm/lei:EntityStatus|
                    lei:Registration/lei:InitialRegistrationDate|
                    lei:Registration/lei:LastUpdateDate|
                    lei:Registration/lei:RegistrationStatus|
                    lei:Registration/lei:NextRenewalDate|
                    lei:Registration/lei:ManagingLOU|
                    lei:Registration/lei:ValidationSources                   
                    ">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="
                    lei:Entity/lei:BusinessRegisterEntityID/@register
                    ">
        <xsl:attribute name="register">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="
                    lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Line1|
                    lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:City|
                    lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:Country|
                    lei:Entity/lei:LegalAddress/lei:PostalCode                   
                    ">
          <xsl:attribute name="legaladdress_{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="
                    lei:Entity/lei:HeadquartersAddress/lei:Line1|
                    lei:Entity/lei:HeadquartersAddress/lei:City|
                    lei:Entity/lei:HeadquartersAddress/lei:Country|
                    lei:Entity/lei:HeadquartersAddress/lei:PostalCode                   
                    ">
        <xsl:attribute name="headquarter_{local-name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </lei:LEIRecord>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```